# tcpdump capture stops after 10 minutes

Tags: linux, windows, tcpdump, packet-capture

I'm trying to capture all my networking with tcpdump.

I'm using `tcpdump -i {} -W 5 -C 10 -w capfile`. After 10 mints (+-) the capture stopped for some reason, and tcpdump is still running.

Maybe there is a parameter for how much time to capture?
I Know the -G parameter, but it's rotate the pcap files.

If someone know why it's happened and how can I fix that, to capture for unlimited time I will be grateful :)

- I'm using tcpdump on windows.

By the way, there is any way to use -i "eth0" on windows? Because on windows I need to check my interface number and use it like this -i "3".

Thanks.

Comment: You're using `tcpdump` on Windows?  Do you mean `windump`?  If you really mean `tcpdump`, then how are you running it - under WSL?  Maybe this is the problem?  You could try running `tshark`, `dumpcap`, `windump`, `rawcap`, ... instead?  With respect to your interface name/number, you use the `-D` option to find your interfaces and then use the applicable interface index number, n, to capture from that interface, e.g., `-i n`.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.